# Remove XML namespace when copy with XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:urn="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="//urn:socket-binding-group">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <urn:socket-binding name="https" port="${{jboss.https.port:8443}}"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to transform this XML file:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

To be like:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

But the result of the transform is:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <urn:socket-binding xmlns:urn="urn:jboss:domain:3.0" name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

It has some extra xmlns attribute. Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only small change in the namespace declaration and here is the modified xslt

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="//*:socket-binding-group">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <socket-binding name="https" port="${{jboss.https.port:8443}}"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. But can I know the reason too?

Comment: As mentioned, using default namespace. Changed from `xmlns:urn="urn:jboss:domain:3.0"` to `xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0"` which avoids that explicit namespace. Also minor changes from `<xsl:template match="//urn:socket-binding-group">` to `<xsl:template match="//*:socket-binding-group">`. And change from `<urn:socket-binding name="https" port="${{jboss.https.port:8443}}"/>` to `<socket-binding name="https" port="${{jboss.https.port:8443}}"/>`

Comment: The key thing is that for literal result elements in the stylesheet (like socket-binding) the in-scope namespace bindings (both prefix and URI) are copied from the stylesheet. If you use xsl:copy to create an element with a (p1=uri1) namespace binding, and use a literal result element to create an element with a (p2=uri1) namespace binding, then you will end up with a result document that has two namespace prefixes p1 and p2 both bound to the same URI uri1.